# Bokeh chart: add tooltip to each scatters on the same figure

Tags: bokeh

i have one line and two scatters on the same figure, the line should have standard tooltip but each scatter should have his own tooltip. how can i add tooltips for each scatters (scatter1 and scatter2)? Or maybe it is impossible?

here is my code, but it doesn't work

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

data0x=range(0,10)
data0y=np.full((10),fill_value=10)
data1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
data2 = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34]])

source_1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=data1[:,0],
    y=data1[:,1],
    c0=data1[:,2],
))
source_2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=data2[:,0],
    y=data2[:,1],
    c1=data2[:,2],
    c2=data2[:,3]
))

f1 = figure( title='figure 1', x_axis_type="datetime", tools='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select,zoom_in,zoom_out,', sizing_mode="stretch_width", plot_height=600) 
# f1.add_tools(htt)
f1.line(x=data0x, y=data0y, legend_label='line', line_color='gray', line_dash="solid", line_width=0.8)
f1.scatter(x=data0x, y=data0y, legend_label="line", fill_color='gray', line_color="gray", size=2)

r1 = f1.scatter(source=source_1, x='x', y='y', legend_label="scatter1", fill_color='green', line_color="green", size=8)
f1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r1], tooltips=[
    ("index", "$index"),    
    ("x", "$x"),
    ("y", "$y{0.00}"),
    ("c0", "$c0")], 
    formatters={
        '@x': 'datetime',
        '@{y}': 'printf',  }))
r2 = f1.scatter(source=source_2, x='x', y='y', legend_label="scatter2", fill_color='red', line_color="red", size=8)
f1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r2], tooltips=[
    ("index", "$index"),    
    ("x", "$x"),
    ("y", "${y}{%0.2f}"),
    ("c1", "$c1"),
    ("c2", "$c2")], 
    formatters={
        '@x': 'datetime',
        '@{y}': 'printf',}, mode='vline'))

f1.axis[0].axis_label = 'X'
f1.axis[1].axis_label = 'Y'
f1.legend.location = "top_left"
show(f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you did well. Just tooltips are wrong. If you get data from datasource use `@`, x/y coords for figure use `$`

```
f1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r1], tooltips=[
("index", "$index"),    
("x", "@x"),
("y", "@y{0.00}"),
("c0", "@c0")], 
formatters={
    '@x': 'datetime',
    '@{y}': 'printf'}))
```